# CSS Responsive - Prevent standalone item

Tags: css

I have code like this:

```css
.user {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.username {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="user">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://i.pravatar.cc/16" alt="">
    <div class="username">David James</div>
  </div>
   <div class="user user2">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://i.pravatar.cc/16" alt="">
    <div class="username">David Something James</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When resizing the screen from big to small like this:
[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5bBW.png)
I don't want to see the second avatar stands alone, I want it to go to a new line along with the username. The username is required to break to a new line word by word when resizing.

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try display:inline-block; instead of inline for the class user.

```
.user {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: "The username is required to break to a new line word by word when resizing." When using "inline-block", it will move the whole text to a new line, that's not what I want.

Comment: Checkout this url:- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjmxWR

add .avatar{ display:inline }

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wants to see avatar alone, simply you can use white-space:nowrap.

I Hope below code will help you...

```css
.user {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.username {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="user">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://i.pravatar.cc/16" alt="">
    <div class="username">David James</div>
  </div>
   <div class="user user2">
         <img class="avatar" src="http://i.pravatar.cc/16" alt="">
    <div class="username">David Something James</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's doesn't work. The username go down at once, I want it go down word by word.

Comment: if you wants to go down word by word your code is working fine. in attached screen avatar is alone because there is no sufficient space for a single word.

Comment: But the thing is the questioner doesn't want the avatar to be alone.

Answer (score 0):

In the container-class use flex and flex-wrap.

It should sort it out. :)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```